multiple sniffers with scapy using tornado
I have 3 scripts:

scriptA: creates a certain type of connection to a server using scapy and responds to some sort of keepalive packets it finds using AsyncSniffer(). This works fine.
scriptB: sends a packet (we'll call it packetA) using scapy, then sniffs for a result (packetB) that contains a particular ID sent with packetA, and filters various pieces of data from packetB into a json string. This works fine.
scriptC: starts up scriptA then runs an API, using tornado, that can receive a POST request to run scriptB and return the resulting json string. This works fine as long as I do only one API request at a time.

When I try multiple simultaneous API requests, the part of scriptB that sends packetA works fine, and it sends multiple packetA's almost simultaneously. However, it only will sniff for one packetB.
Seemingly, the sniffers or timers are using some shared resource that only allows one to work.
I tried using both standard sniff() and AsyncSniffer(). It doesn't seem to matter.
I tried calling scriptB as a separate subprocess call to avoid shared resources. It doesn't seem to matter.
I tried running multiple shells with simultaneous identical/similar AsyncSniffer instances. They don't seem to step on each other.
I am thoroughly confused. Any ideas?
Here is what my code looks like:
scriptC:
from tornado.ioloop import *
import tornado.web
from tornado import gen
from tornado.escape import json_decode

from scapy.all import *
import random
import json
import time
import scriptA
import subprocess

def checkAr(Ar,keyname,defaultval=None,strict=False): 
    if keyname in Ar:
        return Ar[keyname]
    else:
        if strict == True and defaultval == None:
            raise KeyError
        else:
            return defaultval

def incr_Arrval(Arr):
    #just do an inplace increment the first variable in the array. allows for global mutability
    Arr[0]=Arr[0]+1
    return Arr

class send_my_request(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    global myVal, process_running

    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        process_running=True
        error_message =''
        try:
            if "{" in self.request.body.decode('utf8') :
                myargs = json.loads(self.request.body.decode('utf8').replace("\'", "\""))
                val2 = str(checkAr(myargs,"val2",None,True))
            else: 
            #e.g. application/x-www-form-urlencoded
                val2 = str(self.get_argument("val2"))

        except (tornado.web.MissingArgumentError, ValueError,KeyError) as e:
            error_message = f"Invalid or missing argument: {str(e)}"
            self.set_status(400)
            process_running=False

       if process_running :
            command1="python3 scriptB.py --action=send --myVal=" + myVal + " --val2="+ val2 + ""
            json_data = yield self.run_command(command)
            self.set_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            self.write(json_data)
       else:
            if error_message=='':
                error_message="error connection is timed out or not established"
                self.set_status(400)
            self.write({"error": error_message})

    @gen.coroutine        
    def run_command(self, command):
        process = tornado.process.Subprocess([command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        yield process.wait_for_exit(raise_error=False)
        output = process.stdout.read()
        json =output.decode('utf-8')
        print("this is the output : " + json)
        raise gen.Return(json)

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([(r"/sendrequest", send_my_request),],debug = True,autoreload = True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    myVal=['']
    scriptA.startup(myVal)
    time.sleep(2)            
   
    app = make_app()
    port=889899
    print("ready for request")
    app.listen(port)
    #print(f"Server is listening on localhost on port {port}")
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()


relevant part of scriptB (LayerType1 and LayerType2 are built into scapy):
def get_id_and_pkt(pkt,myId,ids):
    a=False
    try:
        current = pkt[LayerType1]
        while current:
            a= MyLayerR(current.data)[LayerType2].layerid
            if str(a) == myId:
               ids[myId]=current.data
               return True
            else:
               current = current.getlayer(LayerType1, 2) #some packets have many LayerType1s so check them all by moving which is current
    except:
        #a= b'0' #dummy value
        a=False
    return a

def send_and_read(my_built_packet,destip,val2):
    myId=my_built_packet[LayerType1].data[LayerType2].layerid
    sniffer=None
    try:
        ids[myId]=''
    except NameError:
        ids={}
        ids[myId]=''
    #run the sniffer until the id is myId or timeout. if it is present add the packet to ids[myId]
    sniffer = AsyncSniffer(filter = 'src host '+destip,lfilter=lambda x: LayerType1 in x and get_id_and_pkt(x,myId,ids),store=0,timeout=10,count=1)
    sniffer.start()
    while not(sniffer.running):
       print("haven't started yet") # this shouldn't happen but should prevent inconsistencies if something lags
       time.sleep(0.02)
    send(my_built_packet,verbose=0)
    while sniffer.running:
        time.sleep(0.01)

    if len(ids[myId])==0:
        data = {"errorCode": '9999'}
        del ids[myId]
        if sniffer.running:
            sniffer.stop()
            sniffer=None
    else:
        #read response 
        data=read_response( ids.pop(myId) )
        if sniffer.running: #should not be
            sniffer.stop()
            sniffer=None
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    return json_data


I would be happy to find a different answer, but I think that the best answer might be to have a single AsyncSniffer, with no timeout, that stores all possibly matching packets in the global dict "ids".
Then, after sending, I could poll "ids" for 10 seconds for the entry with the index == myId.
It's a tradeoff in memory, and I'd have to have a separate function that cleans old entries from "ids", but it should prevent any issue with shared resources, and it actually might be faster.

while this worked perfectly, i would still like to find out why it didn't before
